# Sort Dates using HeapSort in C++

Tags: c++, algorithm, sorting, c++11, heapsort

I have done the part in sorting integers using heapsort. But I am struggling in building the logic to sort dates.

> For example: February 22 1956,March 24 1856,March 22 1856.
>
> The output I required is: March 22 1856, March 24 1856,February 22 1956.

How can I do this in c++ using heapsort?

Comment: Convert dates to integers (e.g. represent `February 22 1956` as 19560222), sort those, convert back.

Comment: Thank you, got the logic

Answer (score 2):

Make a function that compares two dates,

for example

```
bool dateCompare(Date d1, Date d2) {
    if(d1.year>d2.year) return true; //d1 is sooner
    else if(d2.year>d1.year) return false; //d2 is sooner
    else {
        //the years are equal, compare months the same way
    }
}
```

or convert dates to integers and sort them

Answer (score 1):

Depending on how your dates are structured internally you will need to supply a compare method. If utilizing the STL a compare would look something like:

```
struct Date {
  int year;
  int month;
  int day;
};
bool operator<(Date const& lhs, Date const& rhs) {
    return std::tie(lhs.year, lhs.month, lhs.day)
         < std::tie(rhs.year, rhs.month, rhs.day);
}
```